# cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object with agent.request

Tags: python, twisted

I am learning - how to send a request to the browser with `twisted` then get the headers and print them. However, I find myself getting the following error when I run:

```
 python agent_request.py http://www.google.com/

> cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

def printHeaders(response):
    print('HTTP version:', response.version)
    print('Status code:', response.code)
    print('Status phrase:', response.phrase)
    print('Response headers:')
    for header, value in response.headers.getAllRawHeaders():
        print(header, value)

def printError(failure):
    print(sys.stderr, failure) 

def stop(result):
    reactor.stop()
    
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print(sys.stderr, "Usage: python print_metadata.py URL") 
    exit(1)

agent = Agent(reactor)

headers = Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted WebBot'],
                   'Content-Type': ['text/x-greeting']})
d = agent.request('HEAD', sys.argv[1], headers=headers)
d.addCallbacks(printHeaders, printError)
d.addBoth(stop)
reactor.run()
```

Expected output:

```
HTTP version: ('HTTP', 1, 1)
    Status code: 200
Status phrase: OK
    Response headers:
    X-Xss-Protection ['1; mode=block']
    Set-Cookie ['PREF=ID=b1401ec53122a4e5:FF=0:TM=1340750440...
    Expires ['-1']
    Server ['gws']
    Cache-Control ['private, max-age=0']
    P3p ['CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/...
    Content-Type ['text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1']
    X-Frame-Options ['SAMEORIGIN']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Python 3 `sys.argv` is a list of `str`.  However, `Agent.request` accepts a value of type `bytes` as its 2nd argument.  Since `sys.argv[1]` is a value of type `str` something goes wrong somewhere in the implementation and you get this obscure exception.

If you encode `sys.argv[1]` to bytes (eg `sys.argv[1].encode("ascii")`) and pass the result to `agent.request` then you'll get past this error.